# Can overloaded functions' different variations be mapped in the same map?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
string read(string a){return "abc";}
void read(float a){}
bool read(int a){return true;}
int main()
{
    map<string,string(*)(string)> f1;
    map<string,void(*)(float)> f2;
    map<string,bool(*)(int)> f3;
    f1["read"]=read;
    f2["read"]=read;
    f3["read"]=read;
    string t,u;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>t>>u;
        if(!f1.count(t)||!f2.count(t)||!f3.count(t)) cout<<"Unknown command!\n";
        else cout<<f1[t](u);
    }
}
```

Here I want to access these overloaded functions through their keys. But how can I (or can I ever) store them all in one single map? Something like `map<string,/*---*/> f;` that is capable of mapping different functions that have different parameter types and different return types so that I can use `f["read"]=read;` at once?

Comment: how would you use the functions once they are in the map? At some point you need to know what type of function it is

Comment: @idclev463035818 I intend to convert `u` from `string` to `int` or `float` within that infinite `while` loop. So this doesn't change or solve my question.

Comment: may not change your question but it affects the solution. Can you give a bit more context? I mean in your example `u` is always a `std::string` that you pass to `f1[t]`, how do you want to call `f[t]` when it can be different types of functions?

Comment: @idclev463035818 The user will enter `read story` or `read page 4`. So the `read` function must be overloaded that it will be called with `string a` or `string a, int b` parameters for example. I also intend to have other functions that return `bool` values in the same map. Is it possible? (I'll change that `cin>>t>>u` to `getline(cin,t)` as well.)

Comment: what i am trying to convey is that putting functions in the map is the "easy" part, the difficult part is that once they are in the map you still need to decide in the calling code whether you call `f1[t](u);` or `f1[t](u,second_param);` hence it will be simpler to eg make all function take a string as parameter and let the functions do the parsing

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'll write an another function that parses the result coming from `getline(cin,t)` and divide it into sections. If there are any numbers within `t`s value, it will be converted to `int` and pass as an integer parameter.

Comment: hum sorry I missed an important detail ;). The first problem here is that you want to have different overloads as one element in the map. Other elements in the map will have different overloads ? Or all will have those three overloads?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Some other elements in the map will have different overloads and some will not be overloaded at all. I want to put all the functions in this map and access to them with their keys easily. The program will check if `f[t]` is in that map and choose which overloaded variation to call. Is it possible to store them all in the same map now? And thanks for your help so far, I appreciate it :)

Comment: I am still trying to understand how you intend to use that map. Also for the return value you need to know what it is otherwise you cannot use the function properly.

Comment: you will need to know what overload you want to call before you call it. Because you need to convert the string you read either to a `float` an `int` or a `string` but at that point you could as well have 3 different functions, so why do you want overloads?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm tying to call functions by their names at runtime at the console window with user-input string commands. Entering `read story` will call `string read(string a)` variation of `read` while entering `read page 14` will call `string read(int a)` variation of `read`. And there will be other functions than `read`. When `quit game` is entered, `bool quit(string a)` will determine what to return. And all I want to do is, putting these `read` and `quit` (and etc) functions in the same map so user will be able too access them at runtime.

Comment: @idclev463035818 To answer your new comment, I want to relate these operations to one single `string` so the key is always a `string` but mapped value differs. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: the input you read from the user will be always a string, how do you decide if `"14"` is a string or an `int` ?

Comment: the whole thing is possible, but I have no clue how to do it with overloaded functions

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm thinking of using `find_first_of` command in the string so that it will detect numbers if there is any. Then `substr`, `strcpy` and `atoi` will turn it to `int`.

Comment: ok, then back to what i suggested above, why not put functions in the map that all take a string as parameter, do the parsing and call the actual functions (that can be overloaded)

Comment: @idclev463035818 So it's not possible with overloaded functions?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Hmm, it makes sense. Okay, I'll do it the way you suggested. It should work, thank you for your responses and your patience.

Comment: You can put objects with overloaded member functions in the map, but as you want functions with different sets of overloads, this also wont help

Comment: if you wait a sec, i'll post an answer with what I would suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a set of overloads as one element in a map. You could put some objects in the map that have overloaded member functions, though that also wont help, as you want elements in the map with different overloads.

Next problem is that when the parameters are from user input, you need to decide what overload you want to call **before** you call it. Usually you let the compiler decide based on paramters, but here you need to parse user input to the type of the parameters.

Further, elements in the map must all be of same type. That type should provide an interface that allows you to call the functions in a convenient way.

In other words, the easy way is to wrap functions into something that always takes the same paramter and always returns the same and then put that something into the map. I suggest to use `std::istream` for input and `std::ostream` for output :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
std::string read(std::string a){return "abc";}
void read(float a){}
bool read(int a){return true;}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,std::function< void(std::istream&,std::ostream&)>> f;
    f["read"] = [](std::istream& in,std::ostream& out){
        std::string input;
        in >> input;
        // put logic to decide what overload to call here
        bool call_string = true;
        bool call_int = false;
        bool call_bool = false;
        if (call_string) {
            out << read("foo");
        } else if (call_int) {
            out << read(42);
        } else if (call_bool) {
            //note : read(bool) returns void
            read(false);
    };    

    // use the map:
    std::string t;
    std::cin >> t;
    f[t](std::cin,std::cout);    
}
```

For input "read 42" the output is

```
abc
```

[Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Oyg7Y8HscoUNUiwN)

PS: I you wouldn't insist on overloads the parsing could be automated to some extend by deducing the argument and return types of the functions to be put in the map, though it wont work with overloads (and would be a different question).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll use this way.

Comment: Uh oh... It turns out that `std::function` is supported since C++11 but my compiler uses C++03. I'll need to find another way, but I have understood your approach to this case and I'll regulate some code to do it with C++03's way.

Comment: @Xemdocia lambdas can always be replaced by handwritten functors and `std::function` was just out of lazyness, actually I would not recommend it here (it is not needed). You could write a base class and put some smart pointers to instances of inherited objects in the map. It is possible in C++03, but you'll end up writing lots of boilerplate, so I recommend upgrading to C++11. Maybe you just have to pass `-std=c++11` flag to your compiler

Comment: Thank you; but my compiler and my pc, both are outdated. So as I said, I wrote a code according to your first suggestions and added it as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I handled the case according to @idclev 463035818's first suggestions, thanks to them.
Here's my recent sample;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
typedef string (*func)(string);
struct demo
{
    map<string,func> f;
}g;
string read_p(string),read(string),read(int);
int main()
{
    g.f["read"]=read_p;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<">>";
        string t;
        getline(cin,t);
        size_t found=t.find(" ");
        if(found==-1){if(!g.f.count(t)) cout<<"Unrecognized command!\n"; else cout<<g.f[t](t);}
        else
        {
            string a=t.substr(0,found),b=t.substr(found+1,t.length()-found);
            if(!g.f.count(a)) cout<<"Unrecognized long command!\n"; else cout<<g.f[a](b);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
string read_p(string c)
{
    if(c=="read") return "Read what?\n";
    else if(c=="story") return read(c);
    else if(c.substr(0,4)!="page") return "Can't read that!\n";
    else
    {
        size_t found=c.find_first_of("0123456789");
        if(found==-1) return "Choose a page!\n";
        else
        {
            int d=atoi((c.substr(found,2)).c_str());
            return read(d);
        }
    }
}
string read(string a)
{
    ifstream counter("game.txt",ifstream::in);
    string x3;
    int line=0;
    while(counter.good()){getline(counter,x3); line++;}
    counter.close();
    string x1[line],x2="\"";
    ifstream x("game.txt",ifstream::in);
    for(int i=0; i<line; i++)
    {
        getline(x,x1[i]);
        x1[i].erase(0,3);
        x2.append(x1[i]+"\n");
    }
    x.close();
    x2.erase(x2.length()-2,2);
    x2.append("\"\n");
    return x2;
}
string read(int a)
{
    if(a<14||a>18) return "Choose another page!\n";
    int page=-1;
    ifstream x("game.txt",ifstream::in);
    string x1;
    while(a!=page){getline(x,x1); page=atoi((x1.substr(0,2)).c_str());}
    x1.erase(0,3);
    x1.insert(0,"\"");
    x1.append("\"\n");
    return x1;
}
```

I put the map into a `struct` so it's also accessible from local functions. Then when anything begins with "read" is entered, program calls `read_p` function with the user-input string as parameter. `read_p` parses that in my easy way and decides which variation of `read` to call. `read` is overloaded to be able to handle strings and integers separately. When a `string` is passed as parameter, `read(string a)` is called; and when an `int` is passed, `read(int a)` is called.

This method works precisely. Mapping the functions that are in the same format and that will parse input, then overloading different functions related to them. If any other user-input commands to be added, we'll just add `g.f["command"]=command_p;` that will parse it and overloaded variations of the function `command`. I'm sure there must be better ways, if anyone wants to help, I'll be glad about it.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to what you suggested is used by Qt framework for event handling. Said framework casts all slot function pointers to `void*` and is cast back before use. The code generation for that is done by meta-object compiler.

I suspect its  a implementation-defined behavior that actually is viable on most of platforms as longs as you properly track which pointer points at which function. Lately their design became more complex to support lambda expressions for handlers.